# callback in setState doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs, callback, setstate

I have the following:

```
addTodo() {
const text = prompt("TODO text please!")

this.setState({todos:[...this.state.todos,
              {id:id++,
               text: text,
               checked:false}]})

console.log(this.state)
}
```

the console shows an empty array which makes sense as setState is asyncronous.  I change the function to use a callback:

```
addTodo() {
const text = prompt("TODO text please!")

this.setState(function(prevState){
              return {todos: [...prevState.todos,
                     {id: id++,
                      text: text,
                      checked: false}  ]}
})   
console.log(this.state)
}
```

console.log is still showing an empty array.  Doesn't the use of the callback update setState?

Comment: You can check this [post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b) to clear your concerns on state transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` function's second argument should be the function which need to be called after setting the `state`. So you should pass callback as second argument like this

```
this.setState({
        todos:[
               ...this.state.todos,
               {id:id++,text: text,checked:false}
             ]
        },() => {console.log(this.state)})
```

Comment: sorry about that